# Cannot fill ListView with Items in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fill a ListView with Items. Everything seems to work perfectly but ListView doesn't show Items. I am wondering if I miss a step here.

Please take a look at my code below;

```
ListView listView = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listViewLocations);

List<WMS_Location> list = (List<WMS_Location>) response.body();
String listViewItems[] = new String[list.size()];
for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
    listViewItems[i]= list.get(i).getCode().toString().toUpperCase();
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  listViewItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

NOTE: I am sure that listViewItems is not empty and it has 5 string object in it.

Comment: Are you sure that `list` isn't empty after parsing the response body?

Comment: @karllindmark, I am sure that it is listViewItems is not empty, it has 5 string object. I checked it. But, I am trying to fill ListView in a Fragment, does it matter?

Comment: Maybbe "code" is empty and is showing a list of 5 empty `String`s that may looks like empty?

Comment: Have you tried to play with the "visibility" attribute of the listview? Either in java or xml

Comment: Add something like `System.out.println("List item " + i + " = '" + listViewItems[i] + "'");` inside your for loop after you set the array value and share what you see here.